# FFserver-FFmpeg Missing Audio stream which is needed

Tags: server, sound, ffmpeg, stream

I have been playing around with ffserver, and ffmpeg to set a real time stream with my webcam.
I once (actually 4-5 times) got it to work but now every time I try to launch the server I got this error:
Missing Audio stream which is needed for this ffm.

Here is how I launch it:

```
ffserver -f ffserver.conf & ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

I tried to modify many things in the `ffserver.conf` file such as different video format /codec putting the line NoAudio removing it etc...
I even try, with a video file containing audio instead of the camera, it doesnt change anything...
I can't got it to work any more.

I am quite desperate, because I searched the web for an answer, but didn't find anything...
I hope some people here can help or at least submit ideas or thoughts, at this point I am taking anything!

Answer (score 3):

so I found the solution myself!
So  you have to add NoAudio in the  block to be sure, it's mandatory or not depending on the format you use.
The thing is if you tried to launch ffserver and it doesnt work, due to some mistakes in the ffserver.conf files, it's not enough to correct them, you need to close the shell where you tried to launch it, re-open a new shell and retry, otherwise the error happens again for some ultra weird reasons.

Same for all the errors, you have to correct your ffserver.conf, close the shell where you tried to launch it, and open a new one to try to start the server again.

Hope this can help few of you.

Comment: I have NoAudio in my <Stream feed.webm> but when I start ffserver Im getting `Missing audio stream which is required by this ffm`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was that I was using the default `ffserver.conf` (as found in the `doc` directory of the source distribution and in `/etc/ffserver.conf` of the Ubuntu FFmpeg package).  The default `ffserver.conf` has two different `<Stream>` blocks blocks that use `feed1.ffm`, and I hadn't realized this, so even though I marked the first stream block as `NoAudio`, the second stream block was still requiring it.

Switching to a minimal `ffserver.conf` containing only the blocks and directives I needed fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to kill the shell itself (bash, most likely) but just the `ffserver` process, then restart it.  This usually amounts to just using (in that shell window) <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Up-Arrow</kbd> (or <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>), and return.

I'm running my `ffmpeg` from inside of the `/etc/ffserver.conf` file using Launch (in a Feed section), so restarting `ffserver` does everything.  A basic Launch line might look like:

```
Launch ffmpeg -r 5 -i /dev/video0
```

To see if you have any strays running, use this (rather casual command) in a second window:  `ps -ef | grep ff`